# Baggage limit for Cathay Pacific Airlines flights ex North America

Tags: air-travel, luggage, cathay-pacific

I am flying with Cathay Pacific from North America to Hong Kong and switching planes from Hong Kong to Malaysia. I do not understand their policy even when I called them they gave me answer as 23kg when I gave destination. Which one should it apply for me, 23kg or 20kg?

Policies:

> Passengers on Economy Class to/from North America should note that free checked baggage allowance will be revised to 23kg (50lb)

Somewhere on their site says:

> While other routes other than Central, North and South Americas weight limit is 20kg (44lbs).

Comment: Which airline is this? Every airline has their own policies, and without knowing this, we can't accurately answer.

Comment: Cathay Pacific Airlines

Comment: Note that if your bag weights less than 20 kg, it will also weight less than 23 kg (I have been downvoted for suggesting something like that before but that's an easy, practical approach to travel without worry).

Comment: I have backup plan to remove something heavy if its over the limit as I am just near the borderline 20kg limit right now. I know that I will know when I actually check in the baggage. I will probably update to you all guys when that happens if so. But if there is anyone who traveled with Cathay recently, that could help.

Comment: The [website](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_US/travel-information/baggage/check-in-baggage/free-baggage-allowance.html) says 23, you were told 23 on the phone, what's the problem?

Comment: The wording is confusing to me.
TO/FROM means? From America to Any country in the world like hong kong and malaysia? Or does it mean it has to be from america to america?

Comment: In fact, it does even say “Applicable if you are travelling to, from or via the USA […]” and other rules are explicitly about point-to-point flights, all of which suggests that to/from means that if there is a North American city anywhere in your itinerary, then it's 23 kg. Note that Cathay is based in Hong Kong so they probably don't have (m)any direct flights from the US to some other random places. Implicitly, the US is a far-flung destination for them, not the center of the universe.

Comment: They have one intra-American flight leg: [Hong Kong - Yancouver - New York](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_CA/latest-offers/flights/promotion-code-multiple-diy-fares/vancouver-to-new-york.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is better to get it directly from the [source](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_US/travel-information/baggage/check-in-baggage/free-baggage-allowance.html) as @Annoyed pointed out.  If you read it the policy is:

> Weight system – for all locations EXCEPT the Americas, point-to-point flights between Hong Kong and New Zealand* and point to point flights between Hong Kong and Qatar.
>
> - Economy: 20kg (44lbs)
>
> Piece System – for Central, North and South Americas (See Note 3)
>
> - Economy: 23kg (50lbs)
> - Total dimensions of each piece must not exceed 158cm (62in)
>
> Note 3:
>
> Applicable if you are travelling to, from or via the USA, Canada, select Central and South American countries.
>
> Note 1:
>
> The weight of any single piece of checked baggage should not be over 32kg (70lb). Acceptance of any bag weighing more than 32kg (70lb) is subject to prior approval and notification upon booking/ reservation. Overweight items (Exception: mobility aids, medical equipment, sporting equipment, musical instruments, camera equipment, household effects, pets as baggage and diplomatic baggage) will be repacked or split into lighter units during check-in otherwise will not be accepted for carriage.
>
> Any bag exceeding the total dimensions of 203cm (80in) (width + height + length) will not be carried as accompanied baggage unless prior notification is made with us upon booking/ reservation and approval is granted by us.

At issue is applicability of luggage weight for your flight from Hong Kong to Malaysia, which if part of the single itinerary is basically the same trip from US via Hong Kong to Malaysia.

If you purchased 2 tickets separately the story will be different.